# RPC getValue logic - Service id Error in reply RPC Call reply node - Thingsboard

Tags: thingsboard

I am performing an rpc getValue function in Thingsboard using the Knob Widget element.

While i am trying to reply to the rpc call i receive the following error:

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Service id is not present in the metadata!**

This is my input message (metadata):

```
`{
    "deviceName": "eui-70b32121221212",
    "deviceType": "vi",
    "expirationTime": "1687855218871",
    "oneway": "false",
    "originServiceId": "tb-core-4",
    "persistent": "false",
    "requestUUID": "bf1da2d3-a052-4a6b-b1de-1356fa8277a9",
    "targetTemperature": "\"10\""
}
`
```

Does anyone have had a similar problem and perhaps a solution (I don't find anything in the thingsboard documentation regarding this subject)

Thank you in advance.

I tried by chance to put some different service id fields in the metadata but it did nor work.

```
{
    "Service_id": "tb-core-4",
    "Serviceid": "tb-core-4",
    "TB_SERVICE_ID": "tb-core-4",
    "deviceName": "eui-70b32121221212",
    "deviceType": "vicki",
    "expirationTime": "1687855218871",
    "oneway": "false",
    "originServiceId": "tb-core-4",
    "persistent": "false",
    "requestUUID": "bf1da2d3-a052-4a6b-b1de-1356fa8277a9",
    "targetTemperature": "\"10\""
}
```

Comment: I transformed the requestUUID and the originServiceId so that it fits the needed format in the  rpc call reply node but i dont have any sessionId in the message given. 

For everyone who as the issue with a missing serviceId this is the transormation to fix this:

```
 msg = {"targetTemperature" : metadata.targetTemperature};
 metadata.requestId = metadata.requestUUID;
 metadata.serviceId = metadata.originServiceId;
 //metadata.sessionId = "471482a4-1df5-4724-8819-18a3252ecf25";
 return {msg: msg, msgType: msgType, metadata: metadata}; 
```